# spuertest installation issue with npm express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am trying to install supertest but in the terminal i get error, when i run supertest -v says command not found. after installing i get below error. any suggestion would be highly appreciated
i tried to install the dependency with using below methods

1. npm i/install supertest
   2, npm i/install --save-dev spuertest
   3, npm i/install --save supertest

@MacBook-Pro Node_Cat_Supertest % npm install --save supertest
npm WARN cat_supertest@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN cat_supertest@1.0.0 No repository field.

- supertest@6.0.1
  updated 1 package and audited 137 packages in 1.355s
  37 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
  found 0 vulnerabilities
  ahmadimranpopal@MacBook-Pro Node_Cat_Supertest %
  Regards
  IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. have you ever tried it as a root privileges? and got same results? `sudo -i`
2. have you ever tried installing as a global package? `npm install <module-name> -g`
3. have you ever tried to installing specific version of the package? `npm install <module-name>@<version-name>`

Comment: Re9INee thank you very much for the suggestion, i think it worked.

Comment: @imranPopal ur wlc, just marked it as an answer.